# Connection using ConnectionPoolDataSource

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

To connect my required Database. I am planning to use **ConnectionPoolDataSource** class. But *How can i set the details regarding the database name(to which i want it to be connected) on using this instance*. Please Help on this occassion.

Answer (score 11):

Try to read [this](http://original.jamesthornton.com/postgres/7.3/postgres/jdbc-datasource.html) documentation and [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.sql/ConnectionPoolDataSourcegetPooledConnection.htm)

**EDIT**

just modified example from above links

prepared steps:
 - download [MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) 
 - download [mySQL java driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)
 - download [Apache Commons  Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/download_pool.cgi)
 - download [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi)
 - Open MySQL Client like MySQL Workbench and create DB using next script

```
delimiter $$

CREATE DATABASE `test_stackoverflow` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */$$

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `idtest_table` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test_field` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtest_table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow`.`test_table` (`idtest_table`, `test_field`) VALUES (1, 'test1');
INSERT INTO `test_stackoverflow`.`test_table` (`idtest_table`, `test_field`) VALUES (2, 'test2');
```

- create java project, add to class path , myscl connector, pool and dbcp (you just download all these jars)

add next classes

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.cpdsadapter.DriverAdapterCPDS;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.datasources.SharedPoolDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * @author Sergii.Zagriichuk
 */
public class Pool {
    private static DataSource ds;

    static {
        DriverAdapterCPDS cpds = new DriverAdapterCPDS();
        try {
            cpds.setDriver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        cpds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_stackoverflow");
        cpds.setUser("root");
        cpds.setPassword("root");

        SharedPoolDataSource tds = new SharedPoolDataSource();
        tds.setConnectionPoolDataSource(cpds);
        tds.setMaxActive(10);
        tds.setMaxWait(50);

        ds = tds;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

**user name and pass should be changed to your db user/password**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            connection = Pool.getConnection();
            // Do work with connection
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String selectEmployeesSQL = "select * from test_table";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectEmployeesSQL);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                printTestTable(resultSet);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                } // nothing we can do
            }
            if (statement != null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                } // nothing we can do
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                } // nothing we can do
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printTestTable(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        System.out.print(resultSet.getInt("idtest_table")+", ");
        System.out.print(resultSet.getString("test_field"));
    }

}
```

Just run main method and you will see printed test values to console!!!

Comment: u r posts were somewhat useful. But how to implement the instance.

Jdbc3PoolingDataSource source = new Jdbc3PoolingDataSource();

Comment: It is postgress implementation, if you are using other DB you have to use other implementation, for instance there are jdbc driver implementations for each DB engine, like for postgress, mysql, MS Sql, Oracle and so on.

Comment: is "register the DS specifying the CPDS " required or wud the first part itself will do ??

Comment: i included the first part of the code u've provided me.
but they show the following exception.


javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: It was just a simple example, try to read answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353569/am-i-using-java-pooledconnections-correctly and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998159/exception-need-to-specify-class-name-in-environment-or-system-property-java-na to clarify situation.

Comment: I m sorry to ask......but could you provide me a code by i can create a ConnectionPoolDataSource instance and bind it with a logical name. I am planning to make a class which binds the ConnectionPoolDataSource or MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource instance and i can  look it up with from the other java files. It would be a great favour if u help me regarding this.

Comment: Added, it is working, but I think firstly you should understand what are you doing and just after this start to do something.

Comment: Lastly. M sorry to confuse again....don't we have to bind and lookup the objects using JNDI......m not sure abt it...and sorry if i asked anything stupid......

Comment: I've developed non JNDI example, but Pool class you can develop as JNDI if you want it

Answer (score 1):

You could use an instance of [`DriverAdapterCPDS`](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/cpdsadapter/DriverAdapterCPDS.html). This will need to add two libraries, [Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) and [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/). It is very useful when the driver you use does not include an implementation of connection pooling.

You can find a example in http://massapi.com/class/dr/DriverAdapterCPDS.html